# How to count all folder and sub folder in a directory recursive way

Tags: scripts

The task is:  **Output when running the file will be the number of subdirectories (counting all subdirectories in the tree) in the entered directory**.

I know how to recursive a dir using  `-r` but how can i count all these number in a shell script file?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Yeah , it a homework, and i searched the internet but find nothing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `ls -l -R | grep -c ^d` in your terminal from the directory you want to know how many are inside of.

*** edit ***
Use the below to scan with a variable path prompted to the user.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter path to scan:"
read path
ls -l -R $path | grep -c ^d
```

Comment: That exactly what im looking for

Comment: But how can i set custom path to folder?

Comment: You can add the path the command like such ```ls -l -R /usr/share/themes | grep -c ^d 
```. You can add a variable like ```ls -l -R $path | grep -c ^d``` and have $path as a variable input to your script.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: In general, parsing the output of `ls` is a bad idea. I would not encourage anyone. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead

Comment: I edited my answer above to show the variable. Sourav isn't wrong about avoid parsing LS but since you AREN'T looking for file names, rather counting folders, it doesn't matter. it's a simple and clean solution.

Comment: @Roxanna It will still present a problem, believe non-interactive mode uses literal as quoting style, that would mean, e.i., `'folder'$'\n''d'` will give false positive, think any 
 other *quoting style* will do.

Answer (score 3):

To count all the directories *including hidden ones* in a tree rooted at the current directory `.` either

```
find . -type d -printf '\n' | wc -l
```

or

```
find . -type d -printf x | wc -c
```

(you can substitute any single character in place of `x`: if you choose a character that is special to the shell, make sure to quote or escape it). Using `printf '\n' | wc -l` or `printf x | wc -c` instead of passing a list of filenames to `wc -l` will ensure the count is correct even if there are directories whose names *contain* newlines.

Both commands include the starting directory `.` in the count - if you want to strictly count *sub*directories then either subtract 1 or add `-mindepth 1`

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '\n' | wc -l
```

or use `! -name .` to exclude the `.` directory explicitly.

If you want to exclude hidden directories (including possible *non*-hidden subdirectories of hidden ones), then *prune* them ex.

```
find -mindepth 1 -type d \( -name '.*' -prune -o -printf x \) | wc -c
```

---

Alternatively, using the shell's recursive globbing to traverse the tree. Using zsh for example

```
dirs=( **/(ND/) )
print $#dirs
```

where `(ND/)` are *glob qualifiers* that make `**/` match only directories and include hidden ("`D`ot") ones - omit the `D` if you want to count non-hidden directories only.

You can do something similar in bash:

```
shopt -s nullglob dotglob globstar
set -f -- **/
printf '%d\n' "$#"
```

however unlike zsh's `/` qualifier, the `**/` glob pattern matches anything that looks like a directory - including symbolic links to directories.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: @bac0n thanks - added (and updated the other parts with -mindepth for consistency)