# why is output different of counting files?

Tags: command-line, files, find, tree

I just want to count all the files in a directory. I used two method what I found:

1. `tree /home/bkp`
   Whit this method the output is **2177879** file.
2. `find /home/bkp -type f | wc -l`
   And with that one is **2176704** file

What makes the difference? How I could count the all fille under all directories and subdirectories?

Thank you!

Comment: It is a good question here.  However it sounds like one or the other has a bug.  Try doing `tree -d` and `find` with `-type d` for directories, and you get 2 completely different results as well.  The question would be though, which one has the bug?

Comment: Related: [How to count all folders and subfolders...](https://askubuntu.com/a/1360535/986805)

Comment: Hi, I tried both, and different is still exist. with `tree -d` **306647** and with `find` **306760**. I think I don't start to count manually :-D :)

Comment: Try `ls -alR | grep -c '^-'` to count files and compare the result with tree and find (if you didn't add files to the directory since). `tree -ad` (also count hidden directories) is equal to `find -type d`  that could explain the difference between the two. However, I don't understand why `tree /home/bkp` output is greater than `find`. Is this an automatic backup folder or do you think file count may have change between the two commands?

Comment: Even `tree -ad` and `find . -type d` both come up with different totals.  The `find` command will usually come up with a lower count though.

Answer (score 3):

```
tree
# Also output directories but not hidden files
.
├── Directory1
├── Directory2
├── File1
└── File2
```

---

```
tree -a
# Also output hidden files and hidden directories
.
├── Directory1
├── Directory2
├── File1
├── File2
├── .Hidden_Directory1
├── .Hidden_Directory2
├── .Hidden_File1
└── .Hidden_File2
```

---

```
find -type f
# Files and hidden files
./File1
./File2
./.Hidden_File1
./.Hidden_File2
```

---

```
tree -aifF | grep -v '/$'
# Output files and hidden files
.
./File1
./File2
./.Hidden_File1
./.Hidden_File2
```

[Source : How to make tree output only files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232564/how-to-make-tree-output-only-files)

> The `-i` and `-f` arguments cause `tree` to output full paths on each
> line, rather than indenting. The `-F` argument causes it to append an
> `/` to directory names, which are filtered out by the inverted grep
> (`grep -v '/$'`).

```
man tree
-f     Prints the full path prefix for each file.
-i     Makes tree not print the indentation lines, useful when 
       used in conjunction with the -f option. Also removes as much 
       whitespace as possible when used with the -J or -x options.
```